# Check if Username exists in Database

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a register application form. In the code below I want to check if the username exists before i save the data in Database.
The problem here that the code doesn't go to the "else" statement.
Do I miss something? Kindly help

```
public void UserNameCheck()
{


        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection con;
        connetionString = "Data Source=MCOEELIMENEM\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Register where Username= @Username", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.textBox1.Text);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username = " + dr[1].ToString() + " Already exist");
                break;


            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Register(Username,Password,Fullname,MobileNO,EmailID) values( @Username, @Password, @Fullname, @MobileNO, @EmailID)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNO", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailID", textBox5.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Succesfully");
                con.Close();
                this.Hide();
                Login lg = new Login();
                lg.Show();

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use sqloutput to check

Comment: I'd guess that dr.Read returns false if there is nothing to read ?

Comment: Btw, does username Primary Key in your table? or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query will not return any rows (therefore the Read() statement will fail) where the user exists.

Try this (untested):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Register where Username= @Username", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.textBox1.Text);
con.Open();
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (result != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.format("Username {0} already exist", this.textBox1.Text));
}
else
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If `dr.Read()` returns true, then your reader always has rows.

**EDIT:**

As long, as you do not getting any values from DB, you can remove `while(dr.Read())` statement, and your code will work as you need

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to not select all columns, instead just select id and check with `ExecuteScalar` method of `SqlCommand`, that would be optimum solution.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id from Register where Username= @Username", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.textBox1.Text);
con.Open();

var nId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if(nId != null)
{
    // Prompt user is already exists
}
else
{
    // Insert record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check with the number of rows returned by the query.