# Check if username exists in database or not

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I check if a given username exists in the database or not?

I need the program to show whether the username exists when user presses the register button, because currently if I enter an existing username, my program will run into an error and crash.

My table name is called `Login` and insert the table there is `Username` and `Password`.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Proton_System
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\baich\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand cmd;

        private void buttonRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password fields are empty", "Register Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text)
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand ("INSERT INTO Login VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Your account has been successfully created", "Register Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password does not match", "Register Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Login Form1 = new Login();
            Form1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries or you expose your database to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I advise you to use a good authentication library instead of storing passwords in the database and in plain text. At the very least hash the passwords.

Comment: select count(yourusernamefield) from login where yourusernamefield = ..

Comment: As for your question: `select * from [login] where id = ?`

Comment: Do i add it into another else if statement ? If so what do i need to put in the else if ( ?? )

Comment: If it's just a simple implementation, just use the query statement after `con.Open();`, and then do what you want. Simply add a layer of judgment, the crash should be caused by inserting duplicate fields.

Comment: Even if you check if the user exists before inserting the row, it might have been added by another instance just in between. You could use a unique key in the database to produce an error when adding an existing user and handle this error in your code. And: **never construct SQL statements from user input**, as @Tarik already said.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24098341/2558060

Comment: To further comment on @KlausGütter, if you want to check the existence of the user prior to insertion, you need to execute the select and insert in a transaction with, I would guess, read committed isolation level.

Comment: `textBox1.Text` Develop good habits. Give your controls useful names. Anyone should be able to read your code and roughly understand how it works based on those "useful" names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming textBox1 is the username you could use something like this.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand ("select top 1 * from Login where Username = @username", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
bool userExists = cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null;
```

I highly recommend you take some time to read about parameterized SQL queries.
Here's a link to get you started https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx